# Hosted TFS - Run a script on check-in?

Tags: xml, powershell, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm using the (currently free) hosted TFS via VisualStudio.com and Visual Studio 2012.

I have an XML file, that gets edited via a tool that saves the changes in a minimized format (there is no option to make it spit out human readable XML).

This is easily corrected within Visual Studio with CTRL+E, D (reformat document) -- but sometimes people forget to do this before checking it in (which makes merges, harder, and makes the file less readable.)

My question is this: Is there a way to auto-re-format this file on check-in?  Failing that, is there a way to run a (powershell?) script (server- or client-side -- but ideally serverside) in response to the user checking in a file?

I did some searching and found that [someone had mentioned you could write a check-in policy class library and misuse it to modify the files at validation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039661/tfs-check-in-policy-force-a-shell-command-to-have-been-run) (which, even though it's a hack, it sounds great!) -- but that it has to be installed on each individual client machine via a registry mod -- which sounds like a total deployment nightmare to me.  I want the action to just automatically happen without everyone having to install a bunch of crap -- or failing that -- for the installation of said crap to happen automatically.

Comment: You can arrange to have such assemblies downloaded from source control for all members of your team.

Comment: Sure.  But not the registry modification.